# Automatically submits form problem selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium

i am trying to submit the form using selenium:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert New bids</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="home/" id="bids-form">
{% csrf_token %}
<label for="fname">Bid number:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="bid" name="bid"><br>
<label for="lname">Department Name:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="dname" name="dname"><br>
<label for="fname">Address:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="address" name="address"><br>
<label for="lname">services:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="services" name="services"><br>
<label for="fname">start date:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="sdate" name="sdate"><br>
<label for="lname">start time:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="stime" name="stime"><br>
<label for="lname">End Date:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="edate" name="edate"><br>
<label for="lname">End time:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="etime" name="etime"><br>
<label for="lname">Pdf link:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="pdflink" name="pdflink"><br>
<label for="lname">location:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="location" name="location"><br>

<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

and here is my code of inserting data through selenium:

```
 driver.execute_script('''window.open("http://127.0.0.1:8000/insert/","_blank");''') 
                print(driver.window_handles)
                window_after = driver.window_handles[3]
                driver.switch_to.window(window_after)
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/input[2]").send_keys(Bid_number)
                print("line 1")
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/input[3]").send_keys(DepartmentName)
                print("line 2")
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/input[4]").send_keys(Address)
                print("line 3")
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/input[5]").send_keys(manpower_text)
                print("line 4")
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/input[6]").send_keys(start_time[0])
                print("line 5")
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/input[7]").send_keys(start_time[1])
                print("line 6")
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/input[8]").send_keys(end_time[0])
                print("line 7")
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/input[9]").send_keys(end_time[1])
                print("line 8")
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/input[10]").send_keys(pdfHref)
                print("line 9")
                driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/input[11]").send_keys(location)
                print("line 10")
                time.sleep(5)
                # driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/form/button").click
                driver.close()
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])
```

**the code runs till line 2 and after that is autosubmits the form** and i dont know why that is happening.

Note: Values are not null all the varibles have value after line 2 there is no excution of code.

can someoneplease help <3

Comment: The code that you've shared is bit confusing. why are you doing this `window_after = driver.window_handles[3]` ? also which line is second? Is it this one `print(driver.window_handles)` ?

Comment: i opened a new tab with driver.execute_script('''window.open("http://127.0.0.1:8000/insert/","_blank");''')  and then switched to this new opened window.

Comment: and the new tab that you are opening is second tab right in the one session?

Comment: and this above code is for this new opened window... first two input fields are filled by selenium but just after the second input the form submits itself i thought maybe i am getting no values for the variables but its not the case so i comment out my submit button click event but nothing changed

Comment: When you write this line `driver.window_handles[3]` it means you are switching to 4th tab.

Comment: exactly you got it.

Comment: why not directly use `bid` id instead of `/html/body/form/input[2]`? Also I would suggest to use explicit waits. Also, `the code runs till line 2 and after that is autosubmits the form` and you want auto submission right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add "required" arguments in the input tag of the html and you good to go

```
<input type="text" id="address" name="address" required><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Auto-submission might happen when some value contains the new-line char, and while it tries to sendKeys, it presses the ENTER and so the form submitted.

I've checked this hypothesis:

```
driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp")

fname = driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//input[@id='fname']"))
fname.clear()
fname.send_keys('Some Fname')
lname = driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//input[@id='lname']"))
lname.clear()
lname.sendKeys('Some \nLname')
```

and the next data was submitted:

```
fname=Some Fname&lname=Some
```

so, double-check your input data *DepartmentName* or *Address* fields.

Replace all line-breaks with a space:

```
Address = Address.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '')
```